# Удаление куки при выходе с сайта

Tags: jquery, cookie

Добрый день, нужно удалить куку при выходе с сайта

```
jQuery(window).unload(function(){ 
  jQuery.cookie('enter', null); 
});
```

Такое решение удаляет куку каждый раз при переходе на другую внутреннюю страницу сайта, как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: @richarddavis, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: расскажите лучше зачем это вам. возможно найдётся решение получше. если надо удалить куку уходя с сайта - не указывайте ей время жизни, она станет сессионной и браузер удалит её сам когда будет закрыт.

Answer (score 5):

Еще одна практика отслеживания присутствия пользователя на сайте — ставить куки на маленький промежуток времени и постоянно их обновлять. Например, приведенная ниже функция ежесекундно устанавливает куку с длительностью хранения в две секунды. После закрытия вкладки кука про100 исчезнет.

```
var date = new Date();
function track_user() {
    setInterval(function() {
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(2*1000));
        document.cookie = "enter=1; expires="+ date.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
    }, 1000);
}
track_user();
```

Маленькие нюансы:

- Если в браузере пользователя будет открыто много вкладок со страницами сайта, где вызывается данная функция, то кука не исчезнет пока не будут закрыты все вкладки.
- Регулируя скорость обновления и продолжительности жизни куки можно избежать проблем потери куки при обновлении страницы.
- Время жизни куки должно быть больше (не меньше или равным, а именно больше) частоты обновления куки.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){jQuery.cookie('enter', null);}
```

она срабатывает при закрытии браузера, и при закрытии вкладки с вашей страницей.

Comment: при этом использовании получается то же самое: когда обновляю страницу(f5), или перехожу на другую внутреннюю кука удаляется

Comment: @FrancNet

я в параллель добавлю вопрос. А если я сайт открыл в двух вкладках, а потом одну вкладку закрыл, то в второй кука пропадет? (пользователь вряд ли подобное ожидает)

Comment: @KoVadim: Тогда держать в куке «счётчик ссылок» — то есть, открытых табов.

Comment: не уверен, что это просто сделать. Как табы различать? По урлу не совсем верно. По переходам - так же.

Comment: @KoVadim, а зачем табы различать? Сидел, думал, но не смог представить практическую задачу, где необходимо все это действо с куками.

Не поймите неправильно, Я не "докапываюсь", мне реально интересно..

Comment: Насчет "onbeforeunload", так Я вообще не рекомендую его использовать.

Существует несколько ситуаций, когда это событие не срабатывает, например при аварийном завершении работы браузера или конкретной вкладки. А если обработчик события не выполнится, то появятся свободные куки (аки зомби-потоки в multithreading)  могут своим присутствием нарушить корректность работы сайта.

Comment: Есть одна задача. В некоторых случаях нужно, что бы куки были удалены по факту выхода из браузера (например, админка сайта - куки должны удаляться по факту выхода, что бы автоматом разлогиниваться). Все хорошо, но в firefox'е есть [как бы баг, и не баг, а так, фича](https://support.mozilla.org/uk/questions/938865) - там эти куки сохраняются после перезапуска браузера.

Для обычных пользователей оно хорошо - закрыл браузер, открыл - а с сайтов и не разлогинивался.  А вот в некоторых случаях (к примеру покупка через кредитку) куки обязаны удалятся по закрытию браузера.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за пример и особенно за информацию про баг в FireFox.
Буквально только что заметил, что некоторые сайты запрещают одновременное воспроизведение аудиоконтента на нескольких вкладах. Тут тоже куками синхронизация происходит или есть еще какие-то методы?

Comment: о одновременном запрете я не знаю. Обычно у меня некоторые сайты (на которые случайно попадаю), начинают играть музыку и видео одновременно:) а у меня может быть 50 вкладок открыто...

Comment: @uzumaxy можно через localstorage такое делать, там есть событие у window  - storage вызывается при изменении хранилища в другой вкладке:  вот [пример](https://github.com/remy/html5demos/blob/master/demos/storage-events.html) и [демо](http://html5demos.com/storage-events) (для старых браузеров можно и кукой конечно), ещё есть [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) но это немного другое.